# Binding Update Variable

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, binding, runtime

I have a Big problem there and trying to solve it for so long now...

So what I try to do:
- I add a Button to my Wrapgrid with the Codebehind file
- This button should change a variable which is the Source of an Image

```
Datenbank database = new Datenbank();
Binding bind = new Binding("ValueGet");
bind.Source = database;
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;



System.Windows.Controls.Button champbtn = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
champbtn.Name = "btnAhri";
champbtn.Width = 60;
champbtn.Height = 60;
champbtn.Margin = new Thickness(4);
champbtn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, bind);
champbtn.ToolTip = "Ahri";
champbtn.Content = "Press me";
WrapGrid.Children.Add(champbtn);
```

This works. I get my Button and its clickable.
Now as you can see I added some Command Binding to my other Class "Datenbank" which look like this:

```
public class Datenbank : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Source;
    public string ImgSource
    {
        get { return _Source; }
        set
        {
            _Source = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImgSource");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public DelegateCommand ValueGet{ get; set; }

    public Datenbank()
    {
        ValueGet = new DelegateCommand(Ahri);
    }

    private void Ahri(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
        ImgSource = "Ahri_Square_0.png";
    }
}
```

Here is my DelegateCommand class:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public delegate void SimpleEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    private SimpleEventHandler _eventHandler;

    public DelegateCommand(SimpleEventHandler eventHandler)
    {
        _eventHandler = eventHandler;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _eventHandler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

As you can see the generated button should change the string of "ImgSource"

This variable is bound to an imagebox in my xaml code:

```
<Image Height="50" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Source="{Binding ImgSource, Source={StaticResource database}}" />
```

This is ok aswell. So now my problem is, when I press the generated button my "test" messagebox appears, but the image does not change its source and I really dont know how to fix this.

When I manually add a button with the same command as the generated button above, it works fine!

```
<Button Command="{Binding ValueGet,Source={StaticResource database}}">Press ME</Button>
```

It instantly changes the image source and the picture appears, but not with the generatet one and this is important!

So I hope anyone can help me out with this, because I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The image was not build as resource of application/assembly.
Let try.

- Go to Solution explorer.
- Right-click on the image
- Select Properties
- You will see "Build action"

Build action value should be "Resource".

I hope this help.